# How can I delete a Win32 desktop with running programs, and terminate those programs?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-vista, process, desktop

I have this code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HDESK hOriginalThread;
    HDESK hOriginalInput;
    hOriginalThread = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
    hOriginalInput = OpenInputDesktop(0, FALSE, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP);


    HDESK hNewDesktop=CreateDesktop("BasicAppDesktopDesktop",NULL,NULL,0,DELETE|READ_CONTROL|WRITE_DAC|WRITE_OWNER|GENERIC_ALL,NULL);
    /*HDESK hNewDesktop=OpenDesktop("Winlogon", 0, FALSE,
                        DESKTOP_CREATEMENU |
                        DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW |
                        DESKTOP_ENUMERATE    |
                        DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL  |
                        DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK |
                        DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD |
                        DESKTOP_READOBJECTS |
                        DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP |
                        DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS);
                        */

    SetThreadDesktop(hNewDesktop);
    SwitchDesktop(hNewDesktop);
    //system("cmd");
    STARTUPINFOA si = {0};
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\BasicAppDesktopDesktop";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION infos;
    CreateProcess(NULL,"explorer",NULL,NULL,false,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,NULL,NULL,&si,&infos);
    //WaitForSingleObject( infos.hProcess, INFINITE );
    while(!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F12) == -32767))Sleep(50);
    CloseHandle( infos.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( infos.hThread );

    SwitchDesktop(hOriginalInput);
    SetThreadDesktop(hOriginalThread);
    CloseDesktop(hNewDesktop);
    CloseDesktop(hOriginalInput);
    return 0;
}
```

When I press F12, desktop switch to original and program will close, but if I run in second desktop any program, then do not terminates, and when I run my program again, that any program will appears. Is there a way to delete desktops with programs, or automatic terminations of programs ran through second desktop on exit?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to force termination of a program that you started with `CreateProcess` (as in the code you posted), then you can just use `TerminateProcess` on the handle returned in your `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct.

If you want to terminate all processes with threads attached to your new desktop, whether you started them or not, then its a bit (ok, a lot) more complicated. Your code would have to do the following:

1. Enumerate all running processes (using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`)
2. Enumerate threads for each process in turn (again using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`)
3. Get desktop handle for each thread (using `GetThreadDesktop`)
4. Get name of that desktop (using `GetUserObjectInformation`)
5. Compare with name of your desktop
6. If the names match, open a new handle to the parent process and terminate it (`OpenProcess` and `TerminateProcess`)

That's a lot of code to write, but it should work.

Comment: Can you please post sample code here?
I do not know programming in this area.

Comment: @matej - if you the read the MSDN pages for each of the functions  I've given you, the code will almost write itself ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can write a simle DLL that it will return GetStartupInfo using sockets. And you must inject your dll in all processes and execute your dll with CreateRemoteThread and de-inject after the StartupInfo data came.

Sorry for my bad English..